# Add dropdown for chaging the font on site

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a site and I need to add a dropdown on the master page to be able to control the font over the whole site. I want this option to be configured or maintained individually for each user. What is the best practice to do that and is there a feature that can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string variable in the master page and manipulate it from code behind.

In the aspx page:

```
<body class="<%= bodyClass %>">
```

And then in code behind:

```
    public string bodyClass = "fontArial";

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Verdana")
        {
            bodyClass = "fontVerdana";
        }
    }
```

And then make sure your CSS handles the different body classes with the font styles.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use browser Cookie to store color.

When user changes color in dropdown you will update cookie.

Every page will check cookie on load and use color specified in cookie. Or default color if color was not changed by user and therefore cookie is not exist yet.